# Frank Hertz experiment and different jumps

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Why is it assumed that in this experiment, the jump will be between the second and the first states. Couldn't it be that when the electrons have enough energy, an atom absorbs enough to get to the third state and then jumping only to the second, emiting less energetic light?

Isn't this right? Or is it just that the number of electrons that do this is very small compared to the ones that excite the atom to only the second level? I am saying this because I've seen the experiment, and a blue-violet glow is clearly visible when the potential is very high. Unless I have super powers, I cannot explain this, because the light emited from the second to the first level is 4.9 eV is equivalent to light of $\lambda \approx$ 250 nm, clearly out of the visible spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [this article](http://grundpraktikum.physik.uni-saarland.de/scripts/What_really_happens.pdf), that goes into some detail on what actually happens in the Frank Hertz experiment.

To answer your specific question, once you have electrons ricocheting around the mercury atoms, you'll have a significant population of atoms with various degrees of excitation just due to random thermal collisions. The atomic velocities follow a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, and as I recall the Frank Hertz experiment is done at several hundred degrees (to vaporise the mercury), so even with no accelerating voltage a few mercury atoms will be excited by collisions. Once you've ramped up the voltage enough to excite the ground to triplet state you'll have a small but significant population of atoms in more highly excited states that can emit light in the visible region. My guess is that if you pass the light from the experiment through a spectroscope you'd see lots of lines over a wide range of wavelengths.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the article. I'm going to read it.